# How to maintain or force currency formatting in PDF with Aspose

Tags: c#, javascript, pdf, aspose

I'm using Aspose to populate fields in a PDF document from a database.  Getting the value itself into the document is easy:

```
form.FillField("PurchasePrice", PurchasePrice.ToString());  // PurchasePrice is decimal
```

However, when I open the resulting PDF, the field shows up just as a decimal, even though the field in the PDF file is formatted as a Number with the Separator Style and Currency Symbol set.

So, a value of 1200.00 is being displayed as such, though I would expect it to be $1,200.00.  If I change the field manually, ie remove the trailing decimals, the field is updated and displays in currency format as expected.

Is there a way using Aspose/C# or Javascript to force the PDF field formatting to be applied?

The value needs to remain as a numeric value since other calculations are dependent on it, so I can NOT something like this:

```
form.FillField("PurchasePrice", string.Format("{0:c}", PurchasePrice.ToString()));
```

I'm using Aspose.Pdf version 8.2.0.0 and .NET 4.5

Comment: PDF form field formatting essentially is implemented by means of JavaScript code which is executed when the user pressed a key, left the field, or in similar situations. This JS code changes the field content, most often making use of Adobe Acrobat specific JS functions. PDF libraries generally don't have JavaScript interpreters let alone support Adobe Acrobat specific JS functions. Thus, you should format the text you want to put into those form fields appropriately in your C# code before filling the fields.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @mkl.  As mentioned, I'd rather not go this route since there are other calculations that are based on those fields (I suppose I could change the calculations to parse the string into a decimal...) - do you by change know of any document level javascript I could run that would trigger each field's keystroke (such as doc.calculateNow(); will do for all calculation)?  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Aspose.PDF uses incorrect decimal separator i.e. '**,**' instead of '**.**' As a workaround you can try to change your **System locale**.